# for loop iteration over multiple subarrays

Tags: r, loops

I have the variable assignments

```
N <- 10

H <- 10

K <- 2 # number of subarrays 

perms <- 10
```

I set up an empty array as follows:

```
pop <- array(dim = c(c(perms, N), K))
```

Then I assign character labels:

```
haps <- as.character(1:H)
```

Now, I assign probabilities:

```
probs <- rep(1/H, H)
```

I then create a 'for' loop:

```
for(j in 1:perms){

    for(i in 1:K){
    pop[i,j] <- sample(haps, size = N, replace = TRUE, prob = probs)
    }
}
```

'pop' should now contain character labels from `1:H` across both subarrays. Instead, I end up with an error "incorrect number of subscripts on matrix."

I am not sure why R is producing the error.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You gave 2 subscripts to the 3 dimensional vector `pop`. Also the dimensions of the sample wouldn't have matched the dimensions of the slice of `pop` even if you had added a 3rd subscript because the order was wrong.

```
dim(pop)
```

> [1] 10 10  2

You may have wanted this:

```
for(j in 1:perms){

  for(i in 1:K){
    pop[1:10,j,i] <- sample(haps, size = N, replace = TRUE, prob = probs)
  }

}

pop
```

> ```
> , , 1
>
>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
>  [1,] "6"  "8"  "8"  "6"  "3"  "3"  "1"  "9"  "7"  "8"  
>  [2,] "7"  "10" "5"  "3"  "7"  "10" "7"  "1"  "5"  "8"  
>  [3,] "9"  "7"  "1"  "4"  "1"  "3"  "2"  "7"  "6"  "5"  
>  [4,] "6"  "8"  "9"  "4"  "9"  "7"  "10" "9"  "7"  "2"  
>  [5,] "1"  "3"  "2"  "6"  "10" "3"  "3"  "9"  "10" "6"  
>  [6,] "9"  "3"  "8"  "1"  "6"  "6"  "4"  "8"  "8"  "9"  
>  [7,] "9"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "3"  "9"  "8"  "6"  "10" "10" 
>  [8,] "9"  "5"  "3"  "8"  "3"  "4"  "1"  "6"  "8"  "4"  
>  [9,] "10" "8"  "1"  "3"  "10" "2"  "5"  "10" "6"  "4"  
> [10,] "2"  "1"  "8"  "10" "5"  "5"  "7"  "8"  "7"  "6"  
>
> , , 2
>
>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
>  [1,] "1"  "10" "10" "7"  "3"  "6"  "3"  "2"  "4"  "1"  
>  [2,] "8"  "5"  "10" "8"  "3"  "6"  "6"  "6"  "8"  "2"  
>  [3,] "1"  "6"  "1"  "5"  "6"  "3"  "6"  "1"  "7"  "9"  
>  [4,] "7"  "10" "5"  "5"  "7"  "5"  "3"  "3"  "10" "1"  
>  [5,] "7"  "3"  "6"  "8"  "3"  "9"  "6"  "2"  "7"  "3"  
>  [6,] "1"  "9"  "4"  "9"  "1"  "1"  "10" "4"  "3"  "9"  
>  [7,] "9"  "3"  "10" "1"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "3"  "5"  "4"  
>  [8,] "8"  "10" "8"  "6"  "9"  "6"  "9"  "9"  "2"  "4"  
>  [9,] "4"  "6"  "1"  "1"  "6"  "5"  "6"  "6"  "10" "3"  
> [10,] "5"  "9"  "9"  "7"  "9"  "6"  "4"  "2"  "10" "9"
> ```

Though it seems strange to me that you want the numbers in `haps` and therefore `pop` to be characters, but I assume that you have your reasons.

This is a column-wise assignment of the samples. I'm not sure if it matters, but if you prefer row-wise then you can do the index like this:

```
pop[j,1:10,i]
```

Comment: I think `perm` is the first indice. should be `pop[j, ,i]`. Try changing `perm`

Comment: @cderv Right, I was just adding that as an option (row-wise sampling). In this example it won't matter if it's column-wise or row-wise, but depending on the context of the real problem he might want either.

Comment: @Hack-R This is exactly what I was looking for!